# Django form hidden field but previously load with value

Tags: django, input, widget, hidden, modelform

I have a form with 6 fields where 2 of them need to be preloaded with specific values. Then, I need those 2 fields to be hidden since the user doesn't need to deal with them.

I found plenty of questions here in stackoverflow, most of them are applicable to my problem using HiddenInput() method, but when I preload the field, the HiddenInput() method doesn't work any more.

Here is my **forms.py** code

```
class SurveyCreateForm(BSModalForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.wellbore           = kwargs.pop('wellbore', None)
        self.profile            = kwargs.pop('profile', None)
        super(SurveyCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['wellbore'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Wellbore.objects.filter(pk=self.wellbore), empty_label=None)
        self.fields['profile']  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SurveyProfile.objects.filter(pk=self.profile), empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model   = Survey
        fields  = ['wellbore', 'profile','md','inc','azm','time_stamp']
        # Django Form : 2 : Model Forms @2:45
        labels  = {'wellbore':'Wellbore', 'profile':'Profile','md':'MD','inc':'Inclination','azm':'Azimuth','time_stamp':'Date Time'}
        widgets = {'wellbore':forms.HiddenInput(), 'profile':forms.HiddenInput() }
```

and here the html template

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Add New Survey</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <p>
      <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I need those fields to be populated but at the same time hidden from the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would your hidden field have choices? You probably need the hidden field to post something back to the server when the user submits the form, right? If that is the case, then populate the hidden field with the exact value that you want.

Comment: Hi Demetris, you are right. the hidden fields is holding a value that needs to be submitted, but it is not selected by the user, this is why I want to have it hidden. The value depends from the page the user is.

Comment: What are those values? Are you referring to `self.wellbore` and `self.profile`?

Comment: yes, **self.wellbore** and **self.profile**
fixing my broken english:
...the hidden fields hold values that needs to be submitted, but those fields are selected by the user, this is why I want to have them hidden..

Comment: But if they are selected by the user, why should the fields be hidden? I think take some time to edit your question and include more information about what you are trying to achieve, where the data is coming from etc.

Comment: ... since the user doesn't need to deal with them... those fields are populated by the system not by the user. This is why I don't want to show them in the html template, but those need to be submitted with the form.